# Prestashop: Ignore cover image when choosing combination on product page

Tags: javascript, php, templates, prestashop, smarty

I sell T-shirts. The products are a combination of color and size.

I assigned more than one image to a certain combination in the admin and selected one as the cover image:[image]

The cover image is displayed on the product thumbnail (expected behavior)

The cover image is also displayed in the detailed product view (also expected behavior).

However, on the product page, I would like the cover image **not to be prioritized** when selecting a new combination (size or color).
[image]
[image]

When the user selects a new combination, **the first image that is NOT the cover image should appear**, with the cover image still remaining as an option to see the print enlarged.

My knowledge of web development is limited. I don't even know which .php or .js file to start looking into.

Version 1.7.8.8, default theme.

Comment: Apparently, uploading the cover image again, assigning it to the desired combinations, plus un-assigning the cover image from the same combinations will result in the desired functioning.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting the line below the one I marked 'COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE LIKE THIS' in **src\Adapter\Presenter\Product\ProductLazyArray.php** also does the trick. In version 1.7.7.8 it's line 669.

Here's the surrounding code for context:

```
private function fillImages(array $product, Language $language): void
    {
        // Get all product images, including potential cover
        $productImages = $this->imageRetriever->getAllProductImages(
            $product,
            $language
        );

        // Get filtered product images matching the specified id_product_attribute
        $this->product['images'] = $this->filterImagesForCombination($productImages, $product['id_product_attribute']);

        // Get default image for selected combination (used for product page, cart details, ...)
        $this->product['default_image'] = reset($this->product['images']);
        foreach ($this->product['images'] as $image) {
            // If one of the image is a cover it is used as such
            if (isset($image['cover']) && null !== $image['cover']) {
                //COMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE LIKE THIS
                //$this->product['default_image'] = $image;

                break;
            }
        }
```